# My menu is drifting to the left

Tags: drop-down-menu

Hi All I wonder if anybody can help me. My menu seems to drift to the left.
I have been through many other examples on this site and people recommend various answers but none seem to work.

My webpage is as folows

http://www.andrew_drummond.html

Can anybody plese help me.

Thank you sarah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ul#menu has absolute positioning.

Try remove

```
position: absolute;
top: 139px;
left: 0px;
```

Change

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

To

```
margin: 139px auto 0 auto;
```

Comment: I want give you a little suggestion, don't use absolute positioning where it's not important and here is really not